# When i use my ssl link on facebook apps i found error

Tags: php, facebook-apps

Hello when i put my ssl link on facebook basic apps setting that is shared and given from my host hostgator.com then i get the error like

Error

There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later.

my ssl link is

https://secure3001.hostgator.com/~masoom/

i contact to hostgator server administrator but he told me that the error information is not much clear for to solve please get some additional information from facebook that what is the actual error ,so please help me regarding this

Answer (score 0):

> "Word on the web is that FB blocked Hostgator public ssls ....."

from [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681810/cant-change-secure-canvas-url)