# Cant change Secure Canvas URL

Tags: facebook, security, ssl-certificate

Simply trying to change the Secure Canvas URL to  the SSL one provided by hostgator hatchling account (as described at: "http://support.hostgator.com/articles/ssl-certificates/ssl-setup-use/how-to-make-your-facebook-app-ssl-secure") however when tryin to change the Secure Canvas URL the following erroro happens:
Error
There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later.
Word on the web is that FB blocked Hostgator public ssls so if this is the case are there any redirect tricks or something before simmply changing domain or getting one of those personal SSL certs... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Copied this from the first comment in the thread on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/470696239634134/ .  It worked for me!

for hostgator shared SSL you have to add the port 443. example: "https://secure123.hostgator.com:443/~username/"